# Change "Main content" in single drupal page?

Tags: php, drupal

I've been digging around quite a bit but can't find anything definite.
What's the best way there is to change content type design (or "main content" part in page.tpl.php) in Drupal page in a way that only certain page would be affected.

For example in current theme all content types(basic page, article etc.) have white background and time stamp title. 
How can I make it to have my custom design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd use the the node.tpl.php for this kind of customization. Page tpl is a more generic template that covers JS / CSS and overall page structure, which is something you keep standard across the site on most cases.

Using node.tpl.php you can target any type of content type and change it for a specific content type only using node--[content type].tpl.php.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As long as this is the best solution for this problem it does help me, thanks! Although it feels stingy to change drupal files to achieve this kind of task witch imo should be quite common. 
I guess its possible to create custom nodes and make them usable in only certain page?

Comment: Great! You shouldn't override the Drupal files but actually copy that file to your custom theme folder and use it as a starting point to do your changes as required. Drupal will use your file if one exists, or default to the standard one if there's no override. For changes not related to presentation (like defining which fields will be shown and things like that you should probably move it out of your theme and into a custom module - the behaviour of the site shouldn't change if the theme changes, only the look and feel.